# Can not add FMDBx via Cocoapods to my Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, fmdb

I try to add FMDBx(objective C framework) to my Swift project via Cocoapods. This is how my Podfile looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'GBU' do
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
   pod 'Alamofire'
   pod 'RxSwift', '~> 2.0.0-beta'
   pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 2.0.0-beta'
   pod 'RxBlocking', '~> 2.0.0-beta'
   pod 'SwiftyJSON'
   pod 'RxAlamofire'
   pod 'AlamofireImage'
   pod 'FMDB'
   pod 'FMDBx'
end
```

When I try to build my project I get few issues. It sounds like "Include of non-modular header framework module FMDBx.FMXDatabaseConfiguration". I [image]
I tried to set "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" to YES, but it did not solve my issue.